# Writing CSV with `csv.DictWriter` results in empty lines between filled data lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv

I use DictWWriter to write data to a csv-file. The file contains empty lines between my data lines. Present data is put to the rows 1,3,5,7,9, I want to wirte them into the rows 1,2,3,4,5, no empty lines in between.

```
import csv

with open('example4.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'Grade']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'Grade': 'B', 'first_name': 'Alex', 'last_name': 'Brian'})
    writer.writerow({'Grade': 'A', 'first_name': 'Rachael',
                    'last_name': 'Rodriguez'})
    writer.writerow({'Grade': 'B', 'first_name': 'Jane', 'last_name': 'Oscar'})
    writer.writerow({'Grade': 'B', 'first_name': 'Jane', 'last_name': 'Loive'})
```

[image]

Comment: What output are you getting, and what output do you expect?

Comment: Looks fine to me.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: My wish to write data to the next rows in file CSV result (current
data write Row 1,3,5,7,9 in the CSV file, I hope it's written on row 1,2,3,4,5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have found the answer yourself by looking into the documentation.:

[csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

> `csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)`
> Return a writer object responsible for converting the user’s data into
> delimited strings on the given file-like object. csvfile can be any
> object with a write() method. **If csvfile is a file object**, it should
> be opened **with `newline=''`** *[1]*.

And

> **Footnotes**

> *[1]* (1, 2) If `newline=''` is not specified, newlines embedded
> inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on
> platforms that use \r\n linendings on write an extra \r will be added.
> It should always be safe to specify `newline=''`, since the csv module
> does its own (universal) newline handling.

It also provides a small code example:

> ```
> import csv
> with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
>     spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
>                             quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
>     spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
>     spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
> ```